How to hide Tabbar in detail pages/ specific pages in iOS18 SwiftUI?
With Xcode 16 and iOS18, I'm facing an issue with Tabbar SwiftUI.
Now in iOS18, we have a floating Tabbar in the iPad. Earlier, before iOS18, when I pushed any view, a new view was above the Tabbar. So basically Tabbar was hidden and the new view had a full screen to use.
Now with iOS 18 when I push any screen/view, the floating Tabbar is still on the top of the page.
How can I hide the Tabbar on specific screens?

For iOS 18 you use
TabView {
    NavigationStack {
        ContentView()
            .toolbarVisibility(
                .hidden, for: .tabBar)
    }
}

for iOS 16+
TabView {
    NavigationStack {
        ContentView()
            .toolbar(
                .hidden, for: .tabBar)
    }
}

Sometimes you have to make the toolbar explicit visible at a higher level before you can hide it.
.toolbar( .visible, for: .tabBar)


I had a same issue.
If you do not mind using a third party library, I can suggest a solution. It's to use SwiftUI Introspect
In this way it is possible to hide the TabBar in iOS 17.4.
TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
// ...
}
.introspect(.tabView, on: .iOS(.v17)) {
    $0.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

